# Huawei P9 Lite stuck on Vodafone Logo

Tags: recovery-mode, data-recovery, unbricking, huawei

I found my Huawei P9 Lite (VNS-L210) and I wanted to see if it still has photos of my baby brother in it, but I can't. It's stuck on the Vodafone logo. In eRecovery mode, when I try to connect it to any WiFi, it says "Getting package info failed".

I really want my photos back. Please help me.
I am not a phone enthusiast so if you can make it simple so I can understand (if you can't, it's fine, I'll just google it)